# sending mail with unicode through python

Tags: python, email, unicode, smtp

i need to send smtp mail that contains unicode characters (utf-8)

i'm getting this error "ascii codec can't decode byte 0x7d in position 0: ordinal not in range 0-128"

this is my code:

```
for mail in mails:
            sender = 'omris@esg.co.il'
            receivers = [mail]

            message = """From: From server <server@esg.co.il>
            To: To client <client@esg.co.il>
            Subject: SMTP e-mail test

            analysis of %s for company %s just finished
            """ % (subject, custName)


            try:
               smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('code',port)
               smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
               #self.SchedulerLogger.info("mail has been sent to analysts")
               print "Successfully sent email to: ", mail
            except Exception,ex:
               print ex.message
               print "Error: unable to send email"
    except Exception,ex:
        self.SchedulerLogger.error(str(ex.message))
        self.SchedulerLogger.info("send mail failure")
```

custName is in hebrew..

Comment: Do you mean `unicode(custName)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send email using [html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id4) and use [MIMEText](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText)

modify the message as

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
message = MIMEText("""From: From server <server@esg.co.il>
        To: To client <client@esg.co.il>
        Subject: SMTP e-mail test

        analysis of %s for company %s just finished
        """ % (subject, custName))
```